# How to have an option be a part of multiple groups with MUI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have users that can be in multiple groups, defined by the backend. For example, User 1 can be in groups 1 and 2, while User 2 can be a part of groups 2 and 3.

In this case I would like my Autocomplete groups to look like so:

```
- Group 1
  - User 1
- Group 2
  - User 1
  - User 2
- Group 3
  - User 2
```

I'm using this code to do the grouping currently which allows only the first group of the users' groups and it renders as the image bellow:

```
groupBy={(option) => option.native.groups[0]}
```

[image: current groups]

Comment: How do you store your data exactly? Show me the options and groups code.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your data like this structure:

```
option = {group: string, username: string}
```

So your options will be like:

```
options = [
  {group: "Group 1", username: "User 1"},
  {group: "Group 2", username: "User 1"},
  {group: "Group 2", username: "User 2"},
  {group: "Group 3", username: "User 2"},
]
```

And finally in your autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="grouped-demo"
  options={options}
  groupBy={(option) => option.group}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.username}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="your-label" />}
/>
```

Be aware that you should have every item in your autocomplete in your options array.
So if there is a user that is in two groups at the same time, you should have 2 options with that username, one with `group = "group 1"` and another with `group = "group 2"`.
And the data should be sorted of course.
See [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped) for more details.

Comment: I thought of that but wouldn’t you get duplicate autocomplete when you try and search for a user like User 1 since there are 2 entries for it?

Comment: Yes it will behave like that. When you search for a user that is inside several groups, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I would just like to see 1 entry per user.

Comment: Your user is in more than 1 groups. which group do you want it to show?

Comment: When a person is searching for a user, I remove the group headers